# how to make the background perfectly fit the screen without getting stretched?

Tags: html, css

I want the background to be 100% on both height and width. But I don't want it to get stretched/distorted, I suppose the solution here would be to maintain aspect ratio while croping the extra space to keep the 100% value.. Is there a way to do this in HTML/CSS?

Comment: `width:100%;` and `height:auto`

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `background-size:cover;`

There's a good overview of methods here too: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Yes. But trying this on a mobile screen "note 2" It kept a lot of empty space from bottom in portrait mode. It didn't quite fill the page.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has a property called `background-size` which you can apply and give it the desired size, in pixels or percentage, or use `cover` or `contain`, as desired. You may read up on the differences on [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: More importantly, [MDN is a much better reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: Seeing as how this comment does not provide any insight on the question, I doubt this is any helpful. Although I do approve the reference, Google served up W3S as the first result. MDN is a much better reference, indeed.